# Examples of UFDs of form $\Bbb Z[d]$ with $d\in \Bbb C$.

Tags: number-theory

Which values of $d \in\Bbb C$ provide unique factorization domains $\Bbb Z[d]$?

Example UFDs include $\Bbb Z[i],\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-163}]$.

Comment: For algebraic $d$ this is a hard problem, a special case of the class number one problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one), and in particular it is not known if there are infinitely many examples or not. For transcendental $d$ they are all UFDs.